# How to avoid duplicate X time axis labels

Tags: highcharts

I'm creating a line chart using Highstock. However, I found an issue when the date range is less than a specific number of days, duplicate x labels appear. I set formatter to show only days. Here is the example: http://jsfiddle.net/ry4DQ/

```
labels: {
    formatter: function() {
          return Highcharts.dateFormat('%m/%d', this.value);
    }
}
```

When I change the start date to be for example 2011-05-07, you'll see two labels for each day on x axis.

[image: duplicate days on the X axis]

Is there any way to avoid this issue?

I tried the `setExtremes` event, to set `tickInterval` to 1 day when the date range is less than some value, and it works.  However, when the chart is resized smaller, label text overlaps.

Any help or info is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Labels are duplicated because you define label as %m/%d for each extremes. I.e when you have: 18:00 / 22:00 (date range from 2011-05-07), then these values are overlapped by formatter (%m%d). So as a result is duplicated.

tickInterval / minrange should be defined as time in miliseconds, so one day is 24 * 3600 * 1000.

Answer (score 0):

If you remove the `formatter` from `xAsis.labels`, the issue will go away. You might not like the date format though. Here's [the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ry4DQ/2/), and screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The solution by @sebastian-bochan led me in the right path: you can still use your formatter (contrary to @dan-dascalescu 's answer), just make sure to also set the interval to the correct millisecond amount!

```
if hour_axis == true
  date = 'h:MMTT'
  interval = 3600 * 1000
else
  date = 'm/d/yy'
  interval = 24 * 3600 * 1000

xAxis =
  xAxis:
     tickInterval: interval
     tickPositions: 0
     type: 'datetime'
     labels:
     formatter: ->
        dateFormat(@value, date)
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
                xAxis: {
                type: 'datetime',
                tickPositions: 0,
                tickInterval:  24 * 3600 * 1000,
                tickPixelInterval: 110,
                maxTickPixelInterval: 125,
                minTickInterval: 100,
                labels: {
                    format: '{value:%m/%d/%y}',
                    enabled: true
                }
            },
```